# javalang.illegalstateException :setAttributeSessionaalredyInvalidated

Tags: java, managed-bean, illegalstateexception

i got the following error --> javalang.illegalstateException :setAttributeSessionaalredyInvalidated  in my managedBean

```
@ManagedBean(name = "cAcessoSistema")
@RequestScoped
public class CAcessoSistema implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private transient Password password;
    private transient InputText login;
    private transient InputText email;
    private String paginaAutenicado;
    private Acesso acesso;
    private Usuario usuario;
    private String horaAtual;
    private boolean btnEntrarDisable;
    private boolean estaNaHR;
    private Map<String, String> ipsHrtech;

    @PostConstruct
    public void inicioSessao()
    {



    LogManager.getLogger(CAcessoSistema.class).info("teste info");
    System.out.println("verificarIP");


    acesso = new Acesso();
    usuario = new Usuario();




   public String actAutenticar()
    {

    HttpSession sessao = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true); 


    paginaAutenicado = "/protegido/index.jsf?faces-redirect=true";

    acesso = new Acesso(login.getValue().toString(), password.getValue().toString());

    usuario = new Usuario(acesso);

    System.out.println("Acesso" + acesso);
    System.out.println("usuario" + usuario);


    try
    {
        new AutenticadorUsuario().autenticar(usuario);

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().dispatch("/j_spring_security_check?j_username=" + usuario.getAcesso().getLogin() + "&j_password=" + usuario.getAcesso().getSenha()); 


        new ContadorSessao().gravarDadosSessao(sessao);


        System.out.println("Esotou no metodo  1");


        if (Boolean.FALSE.equals(usuario.isAbreVisita()))
        {

            System.out.println("Esotou no metodo  2");


            sessao.setAttribute("estaNaHR", true);



            System.out.println("estaNaHR  ?????  " + sessao.getAttribute("estaNaHR"));

            System.out.println("Esotou no metodo  3");

            usuario.setClienteAlocado(usuario.getCliente());
            new CadastradorUsuario().atualizarClienteAloca(usuario);    

            sessao.setAttribute("paginaInicial", paginaAutenicado);
            sessao.setAttribute("usuario", usuario);
```

the exception is in this part ----->    sessao.setAttribute("estaNaHR", true);

CAN ANYONE HELP ME????

Tbhanks in advance!!!

```
2014-10-14T10:13:31.848-0300|Informações: verificarIP
2014-10-14T10:13:31.858-0300|Informações: AcessoAcesso [login=masterteste, senha=masterteste]
2014-10-14T10:13:31.858-0300|Informações: usuarioUsuario [codigo=0, nome=null, cpf=null, usuarioSkype=null, acesso=Acesso [login=masterteste, senha=masterteste], perfil=null, departamento=null, cliente=null, clienteAlocado=null, contato=null, ativo=false, abreVisita=false, abreVisitaAuto=false, ocorrenciaPendente=false, dataCriacao=null, dataAlteracao=null, cadastrador=null, alterador=null, status=null, visita=null, estaNaHR=false]
2014-10-14T10:13:31.884-0300|Informações: RAR7114: Unable to get ClientInfo for connection 
2014-10-14T10:13:31.891-0300|Informações: RAR7115: Unable to set ClientInfo for connection
2014-10-14T10:13:31.899-0300|Informações: Esotou no metodo  1
2014-10-14T10:13:31.899-0300|Informações: Esotou no metodo  2
2014-10-14T10:13:31.900-0300|Advertência: #{cAcessoSistema.actAutenticar}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: PWC2789: setAttribute: Session already invalidated
javax.faces.FacesException: #{cAcessoSistema.actAutenticar}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: PWC2789: setAttribute: Session already invalidated
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:117)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:786)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1251)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:144)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:807)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:671)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:476)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:305)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: PWC2789: setAttribute: Session already invalidated
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:101)
    ... 78 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: PWC2789: setAttribute: Session already invalidated
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.setAttribute(StandardSession.java:1708)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade.setAttribute(StandardSessionFacade.java:178)
    at br.com.hrtech.atendimento.controller.CAcessoSistema.actAutenticar(CAcessoSistema.java:234)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)


 public void gravarDadosSessao(HttpSession sessao)
    {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();

    String ipInternet = null;

    try
    {
        if (request != null)
        {
        ipInternet = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");// 1º Maneira de pegar IP Internet

        if (ipInternet == null)
        {
            ipInternet = request.getRemoteAddr();// 2º Maneira de pegar IP Internet
        }
        if (ipInternet.equals("0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1"))
        {
            // Pegando IP Local
            ipInternet = request.getLocalAddr();
        }
        }

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date data = c.getTime();
        DateFormat dtHora = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
        String dtCriacao = dtHora.format(new Date(sessao.getCreationTime()));
        String dtUltimoAcesso = dtHora.format(new Date(sessao.getLastAccessedTime()));

        if (sessao.getAttribute("usuario") == null && sessao.getAttribute("dadosSessao") == null)
        {
        dadosSessao = new DadosSessao(sessao.getId(), ipInternet, dtCriacao, dtUltimoAcesso, Boolean.TRUE);
        new CadastradorSessao().cadastrarDadosSessao(dadosSessao);
        } else
        {
        Usuario usuario = (Usuario) sessao.getAttribute("usuario");

        if (sessao.getAttribute("dadosSessao") != null)
        {
            dadosSessao = (DadosSessao) sessao.getAttribute("dadosSessao");
            if (sessao.getAttribute("usuario") != null)
            {
            dadosSessao.setIdUsuario(usuario.getCodigo());
            dadosSessao.setNomeUsuario(usuario.getNome());
            usuarios.add(usuario);

            }
            dadosSessao.setDtUltimoAcesso(dtUltimoAcesso);
            dadosSessao.setIpInternet(ipInternet);
            dadosSessao.setAtivo(Boolean.TRUE);

            new CadastradorSessao().alterarDadosSessao(dadosSessao);
        }
        }

    } catch (NamingException | SQLException e)
    {
        e.getMessage();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Besides sending the StackTrace it would be helpfull for us if we know waht happens in `new ContadorSessao().gravarDadosSessao(sessao)`. If you could send this source code also.

Comment: Added now in the message

Comment: it seems that your method gravarDadosSessao() is invalidating the session somehow, that's why we need to see the source code for it

Comment: Leo thank u i´ve just posted